# Sorting and Filtering in J2EE Application

Tags: java, ajax, jakarta-ee

I have been learning JAVA web development for a while, and have a pretty good handle on Servlets, JSP's, and am familiar with AJAX/CSS/Javascript.

One thing I have seen on a lot of sites is the ability to sort and filter a list of items on a webpage(items in a storefront for example). For example, if I'm looking at a list of shoes, I can filter and show only the ones available in a certain size, and then sort by highest to lowest price.

I see that AJAX is used in most cases, but my question is, as far as the back end is concerned, I'm assuming that the database isn't being queried every time to do the sorting and filtering, so what are some of the techniques for accomplishing this?

Are the objects stored in the session, and then when an AJAX call is made, the filtering parameters are sent as part of the request, and the servlet does the filtering and passes back the results? Is there a pattern generally used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the dataset.  For small datasets, you can, say, return a single JSON request to the client and do the filtering/sorting in JavaScript.

For huge datasets, you'll usually let the server do the filtering and sorting, such that you'd only need to transfer a fraction of the results.  For example, if you want to display 10 products out of a list of thousand of products, server side filtering/sorting is required to keep the data transferred small.

Storing the results in a (http) session seems to be a bad idea to me, as a session has limited size.  You may want to look into dedicated caching solutions (such as memcache) if you are concerned about speed.

Comment: I would agree about doing the sorting on the servlet, but as far as the data is concerned, wouldn't the original data set need to be stored in the users session if the data isn't cached? That way when the filtering options are passed with the AJAX request, the servlet knows what objects are being sorted?

Comment: If you can't reconstruct the original list of objects, e.g., by repeating a database query), yes.  But I can rarely think of use-cases where this is actually the case and no workaround is available.